# Evan's debugger (edb) - Failed to open and attach to process: execv() failed: No such file or directory

Tags: debuggers

### Problem:

When I try to open an executable (in this case exploit exercises protostar stack0), then the following message appears in a pop-up box:

`Failed to open and attach to process: execv() failed: No such file or directory.`

and I am unable to open any files because of this.

Terminal output:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/tools/edb-debugger/build$ ./edb --run ~/proto/bin/stack0 
Icon theme "elementary" not found.
Starting edb version: 1.1.0
Please Report Bugs & Requests At: https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/issues
Running Terminal:  "/usr/bin/xterm"
Terminal Args:  ("-title", "edb output", "-hold", "-e", "sh", "-c", "tty > /tmp/edb_temp_file_787768528_7578;trap \"\" INT QUIT TSTP;exec<&-; exec>&-;while :; do sleep 3600; done")
Terminal process has TTY:  "/dev/pts/5"
comparing versions: [4352] [4352]
```

At first I installed edb using apt-get. This problem occurred. Then I uninstalled and installed it manually from the source code (and fixed the segmentation fault issue by changing the plugins directory). The problem remains. It doesn't matter if I use --run or try to open it from the GUI.

### Version info

I'm using Lubuntu. Linux 5.3.0-18. It's a VM downloaded from OSBoxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/proto/bin$ ll | grep stack0
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root    root    22412 Jan 22 07:16 stack0*
osboxes@osboxes:~/proto/bin$ ./stack0
bash: ./stack0: No such file or directory
```

The program is marked as executable, but trying to execute it says there is no such file or directory. I didn't even notice it, because radare2 and gdb were able to execute it.

After reading [stackoverflow 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists) and [stackoverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716702/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-executing-a-binary), it seems that the problem is that my 64 bit system can't handle the 32 bit executable.

After running the following command, I got the executable to work.
`sudo apt-get install lib32z1`

And also edb started working.

---

Edit: Another reason why it might not work for you is that you have not marked it as executable. In that case:

`chmod +x filename`